# Install network printer on a remote computer

Tags: windows, networking, printers

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I want to be able to sort of manage users' network printers remotely. Which means, either using something like PowerShell or C# to select the computer name or IP address, then choose the printer (which is on a print server so \PrintServer\Printer01) and have it install on the target user's machine.

I've seen something that did say because of permissions, I might have to fake the identity to properly have it installed for the user.

I noticed powershell has a Add-Printer cmdlet, but it tells me it's not recognized on my machine. But running something like: *add-printer -r CompName -p \server\Printer01* would then have the remote computer *CompName* fetch the printer info from the print server and install it.

I'm not dreaming am I? lol

Answer (score 2):

The Win32 functions [AddPrinterDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [AddPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can install printers on remote machines.  However, you will have to copy all the necessary files for the driver to the remote machine's \windows\system32\spool\drivers\[w32x86|x64] directory prior to calling the AddPrinterDriver function.

Answer (score 1):

These Powershell commands can help:

## Add PrinterPorts

```
Add-PrinterPort -Name $PrinterPort -PrinterHostAddress $PrinterIP -ComputerName $Computer
```

## Add Printers

```
Add-Printer -computername $Computer -name $PrinterName -PortName $PrinterName-DriverName "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"
```